# How can I replace multiple correlated subqueries in the SELECT clause by LEFT JOINs?

Tags: postgresql

A fiddle for my question can be found on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e387589d446d9c9a952294f8c7a98494.

I have simple table layout:

```
class
person: belongs to a class
room:   belongs to a class
```

The following query selects all classes with its persons embedded:

```
select    class.identifier, array(select person.identifier from person where person.class_identifier = class.identifier) as persons
from      class
order by  class.identifier;
```

While experimenting and learning more about correlated subqueries, I noticed that the query above could be rewritten by replacing the correlated subquery with a `LEFT JOIN` combined with a `GROUP BY`:

```
select     class.identifier, array_agg(person.identifier) as persons
from       class
left join  (
             select  person.identifier, person.class_identifier
             from    person
           ) as person
on         class.identifier = person.class_identifier
group by   class.identifier
order by   class.identifier;
```

Please note that I made the assumption that each class has at least one person. If not, I could add `coalesce()` around `json_agg`.

In my second case, I am going to select all classes with its persons **and** its rooms embedded. Let's first write in the same manner as the first query above:

```
select    class.identifier, array(select person.identifier from person where person.class_identifier = class.identifier) as persons,
                            array(select room.identifier from room where room.class_identifier = class.identifier) as rooms
from      class
order by  class.identifier;
```

This gives the expected results.

Now I want to repeat what I did before: introduce `LEFT JOIN`s. My first attempt was as following:

```
select     class.identifier, array_agg(person.identifier) as persons
                           , array_agg(room.identifier) as rooms
from       class
left join  (
             select  person.identifier, person.class_identifier
             from    person
           ) as person
on         class.identifier = person.class_identifier
left join  (
             select  room.identifier, room.class_identifier
             from    room
           ) as room
on         class.identifier = room.class_identifier
group by   class.identifier
order by   class.identifier;
```

Now I am getting wrong results. Persons or rooms are being repeated in the output arrays. I understand why this happens (we are grouping on the cartesian product between *class*, *person* and *room*, hence every *person* is repeated for every *room* and vice versa), but I don't know how to proceed.

How can I continue here? Is replacing multiple correlated subqueries in a `SELECT` clause to `LEFT JOIN + GROUP BY` possible to start with, or need I other tricks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can aggregate over distinct values as:

```
array_agg(distinct person.identifier)
```

However, I'm not sure why you are joining against these sub-selects. You can join directly against the tables like:

```
select class.identifier, array_agg(distinct person.identifier) as persons
                       , array_agg(distinct room.identifier) as rooms
from class
left join  person
    on class.identifier = person.class_identifier
left join room
    on class.identifier = room.class_identifier
group by   class.identifier
order by   class.identifier;
```

I would also suggest that you use an alias for your tables. 1- or 2- letter abbrevations will make the query easier to read (IMO):

```
select c.identifier, array_agg(distinct p.identifier) as persons
                   , array_agg(distinct r.identifier) as rooms
from class c
left join  person p
    on c.identifier = p.class_identifier
left join room r
    on c.identifier = r.class_identifier
group by   c.identifier
order by   c.identifier;
```

Oh, and welcome to the site. A nice first question with code and sample data, well done.

Comment: That's interesting. I did not really grasp that you could add `DISTINCT` inside an aggregation. I will have to re-read the documention to find out what is also possible when aggregsting. Regarding your question on the sub-selects: that's a good point, I don't really know why I was doing that. It is probably a leftover from other experiments.

Comment: You can compare with other aggregates such as `COUNT(distinct x)`

Comment: This is all very new and interesting to me, exciting! Also cheers for the kind words.

Comment: I will remember to upvote your answer later on when I reached sufficient points :).

Comment: @JariusHebzo - I think you're allowed upvote and/or mark as correct answers to your own question even with 0 points! You may (was a while ago now :-) ) have to wait for a while before being allowed to upvote/mark as correct. If I were you, I would do both as not only did Lennart provide an answer, he added helpful suggestions (he's teaching you you to fish rather than just handing you a fish...) and gave yoiu a nice welcome to the site into the bargain!